# How to return ratings based on given values

Tags: c#, performance, coding-efficiency

I need a method that returns a rating value based on the given argument. The Ratings class stores the upper and lower limits for a rating as integers (read from a xml file).

Until now I have a method similar to the code below, but I am looking for a "smarter" and more efficient way to get my rating.

```
private int GetRating(Ratings ratings, double rawValue)
    {
        int finalRating = 0;

        if (rawValue <= ratings.Rating_1_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 1;

        if (rawValue >= ratings.Rating_2_lowerLimit && rawValue <= ratings.Rating_2_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 2;

        if (rawValue >= ratings.Rating_3_lowerLimit && rawValue <= ratings.Rating_3_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 3;

        if (rawValue >= ratings.Rating_4_lowerLimit && rawValue <= ratings.Rating_4_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 4;

        if (rawValue >= ratings.Rating_2_lowerLimit)
            finalRating = 5;

        return finalRating;
    }
```

Comment: For starter you need to refactor your code. Ratings should be a collection of Rating classes. Rating class should contain upper and lower properties. P.s. when you want to name properties with numbers - you doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd wager the efficiency of this code is never ever going to be an issue & that there is no effective way to make it (needlessly) more efficient anyway.

Comment: What is the profiler showing? Where's the weak point?

Comment: Do you have `ratings.Rating_N_upperLimit == ratings.Rating_N+1_lowerLimit` (i.e. no *holes*) withing ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance isn't going to be much of a problem in your code. Therfore the only way to improve it would be to shorten it. However, there's not much to shorten, but you could do it like this to be able to scale better if you have more ratings down the road:

```
public struct Rating
{
    public int Lower { get; set; }
    public int Upper { get; set; }
    public int FinalRating { get; set; }
}

private int GetRating(IEnumerable<Rating> ratings, double rawValue)
{
    int finalRating
    foreach(var rating in ratings)
    {
        int currentRating;
        if(rawValue >= rating.Lower && rawValue <= rating.Upper)
            currentRating = rating.FinalRating;

        Math.Max(currentRating, finalRating);
    }
    return finalRating; 
}
```

This codee assigns a rating to a range of values which are then tested against. By passing the ratings as an IEnumerable we can interate over them (and select the greatest rating), while not having to introduce a new if for every new rating. You just add a new rating instance to the ratings IEnumerable and be dine with it.
This is however going to be slower than plain if-else, albeit in bigger programs the speed advantage is outweighed by the much greater maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

This may works in case of bounds are continuous :

```
    private int GetRating(Ratings ratings, double rawValue)
    {
        int finalRating = 0;

        if (rawValue <= ratings.Rating_1_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 1;

        else if ( rawValue <= ratings.Rating_2_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 2;

        else if( rawValue <= ratings.Rating_3_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 3;

        else if( rawValue <= ratings.Rating_4_upperLimit)
            finalRating = 4;
        else 
            finalRating = 5;

        return finalRating;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "efficient", you mean less duplicated code? Because in terms of speed, the code couldn't be sped up significantly. I am also assuming that the lower limit of one rating is equal to the upper limit of the previous one.

Your `Ratings` class just needs to store a list of 4 doubles, which are the boundaries for each rating. Let's suppose these numbers are 20, 40, 60, 80 respectively.

```
public List<double> Boundaries = new List<double>() { 20, 40, 60, 80 };
```

Everything less than 20 has a rating of 1, everything less than 40 has a rating of 2, everything less than 60 has a rating of 3, everything less than 80 has a rating of 4, everything else has a rating of 5.

You can filter out the numbers that are less than `rawValue` and count how many is left. And that plus 1 is the rating:

```
return ratings.Boundaries.Where(x => rawValue >= x).Count() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the ranges are dense, i.e.

```
 ratings.Rating_N_upperLimit == ratings.Rating_N+1_lowerLimit
```

For instance

```
[1_lower_limit..1_upper_limit)[2_lower_limit..2_upper_limit)...[N-1_lower_limit..N-1_upper_limit)[N_lower_limit..N_upper_limit)
```

and you want

```
0     if rawValue < 1_lower_limit
k     if rawValue <= k_lower_limit && rawValue < k_upper_limit
N + 1 if rawValue >= N_upper_limit
```

then you can use *binary search*:

```
// Lower limit, must be sorted  
static double[] s_Limits = new double[] {
    10.0,
    20.0,
    30.0,
    40.0,
    50.0,
   100.0,
};

...

private static int GetRating(double rawValue) {
    if (rawValue >= s_Limits[s_Limits.Length - 1])
        return s_Limits.Length;

    int index = Array.BinarySearch(s_Limits, rawValue);

    return index < 0 ? -index - 1: index + 1;
}
```